# can you partition a logical partition

Tags: partition

in linux i have been working on partitioning and wondering is it possible to partitition a logical partition or further extend a extended partition?

Comment: A partition is just a continuous chuck of blocks on the disk, it can hold any data structure. So, the answer is yes, but normal partition tools might refuse to operate on a partition device instead of a whole disk device

Comment: but is it possible to partition a extended partition, which keep in mind is just a container which logical partitions sit inside?

Comment: Most OS naturally support MBR with extended partition table scheme, which is, as a result,  often considered as standard MBR scheme

Comment: ah ok i see, thanks for clearing that up man. but i have another thing i need to ask regarding logical partitions, so the question is, are logical partitions whole disks or are they just a part of a disk, because ive read that logical partitions are virtual whole disks/drives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (with some losetup hackery), but there is no practical application; the best option for simplicity is a single partition(what ubuntu has), advanced users are going to use LVM, Brtfs, etc which are more flexible/featured than a partition.

Start by reading

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-lvm.html

Or

https://debian-administration.org/article/410/A_simple_introduction_to_working_with_LVM

Or

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM

Answer (score 0):

In the MBR partitioning scheme, one could create two (or more) logical partitions in the same disk area originally used by some existing logical partition by creating suitable logical partition boot records. Whether a given partition editor would do such a thing is another question. The size of the extended partition is just a number in a field of the MBR partition table, which could be increased as long as there is actual contiguous disk space to support it. Typically, the extended partition is described by the last used entry in the MBR partition table, and it encompasses all the disk space from its first sector to the last sector on disk.